# Why did I have to kill -9 neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I asked nicely:

```
$ neo4j stop
Stopping Neo4j Server [74949]........................ lots of dots ......
```

waited a few minutes, asked nicely again:

```
$ kill 74949
$ ps x | grep neo
74949   ??  R     30:13.01 /Library/Java/Java...org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper
```

still running.  Done asking nicely.

```
$ kill -9 74949
```

Why did neo4j not respect the TERM signal?  If it was waiting for something, how could I have found out what?

Normally, I would ask this kind of question on Server Fault, but the neo4j site points here.

Comment: If that happens the next time, please do a `jstack PID` and provide the thread dump too, as it offers insights in what the JVM is currently doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily the descending order of usefulness...

- `ps alx` might have given a hint (process state - but with Java programs the issue isn't that often the jvm itself that died/locked but stuff that's running inside the jvm)
- in `top` 100% cpu usage may indicate an endless loop
- Java processes can end up in a state where all they still do is gc'ing in an almost always vain attempt to free up memory, enabling gc logging can help you detect this condition.
- afaik neo4j is remotely monitorable via jmx (visualvm or jconsole) and I've already used these tools to determine what thread hung one of our Glassfish servers.

Comment: If there's a query running, could that prevent neo4j from stopping?

Comment: did you guys find a solution? how do I stop it?

Answer (score -1):

If you execute kill [PID], you only send (TERM SIGNAL) and the process will close it self gently. If you send SIGNAL number 9 (KILL SIGNAL) the process will end immediately. Regardless of it current state. Signal 9 (can not be ignored).

Comment: I understand the `kill` command, thanks.  Actually, the default signal for kill is TERM.  Otherwise, you are correct, but your answer does not help me with `neo4j`.